# What does effect would Sulforaphane have on Kennedy's Disease?

Tags: vegetable, neurodegenerative-disorders, histone-deacetylase

Sulforaphane is a isothiocyanate found in cruciferous vegetables including broccoli and cauliflower. Its 2D structure is as follows:

[image]

It's been found to serve as a **histone deacetylase 6** (HDAC6) inhibitor and to inhibit androgen receptor expression in prostate cancer cells.<sup>[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2757849/pdf/zpq16663.pdf)</sup> This caused me to become curious as to whether it would do the same in lower motor neuron cells and thus manage to prevent their polyglutamine-induced death and thus halt the progression of spinobulbar muscular atrophy (SBMA; Kennedy's disease).